# Почему-то появляется второй "\"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой, что появляется второй "\"

```
import os

directory = r'img'
for entry in os.scandir(directory):
    if (entry.path.endswith(".jpg")
            or entry.path.endswith(".png")) and entry.is_file():
        test = []
    print(entry.path)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но мне нужен список, я сделал его, и как раз тут это и появилось:

```
import os

directory = r'img'
for entry in os.scandir(directory):
    if (entry.path.endswith(".jpg")
            or entry.path.endswith(".png")) and entry.is_file():
        test = []
        for entry in os.scandir(directory):
            test.append(entry.path)
    print(test)
```

это второй код который как раз создает массив

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если что я плохо знаю python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё нормально, так и должно быть. Символ `\` используется как экранирующий символ, чтобы строка вроде `'string with \'quote\''` распознавалась нормально. И у вас работает только логика отображения, но не изменения данных (`'\'' == "'"`, `r'\ ' == '\\ '`)

По-разному выводится, тк в первом случае вы выводите строку, а во втором случае список, применяется разная логика (условно, так):

```
print(string) => print(string.__str__())
print(list_of_string) =>
    print(list_of_string.__str__()) =>
    print(
        '['
        + ' ,'.join(string.__repr__() for string in list_of_string)
        + ']'
    )
```

В первом случае вызывается `string.__str__()`, во втором `string.__repr__()`, отсюда и разное отображение.

Comment: привет спасибо, но как убрать этот второй \. Просто не дошло

Comment: @DeathWingunity Не надо его убирать, т.к. его там нет. Сами проверьте длину строк с "двойными" слешами.  Например. ` len('a\\b')` будет равна 3.

Comment: Привет спасибо что разъяснил что и как теперь буду знать

Answer (score 0):

Это экранирование вашего символа `\`. Поскольлку символ слэша является спец символом необходимо явно показывать, что в данном случае данный символ будет частью последовательности, символом строки. Чтобы сделать символ частью строки, то надо перед символом поставить знак слэша. На заметку это не обязательно, можно использовать `r-string`. Ссылка в конце ответа

Наглядно можно посмотреть как работает экранирование на таком простом примере:

```py
a = "\"abcde\""
```

где двойные кавычки экранируются и являются частью строки.
Если использовать одинарные кавычки, то экранирования можно избежать в данном конкретном случае, аналог

```py
a = '"abcde"'
```

оф док можно поизучать [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)